# Auto replace numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm making a excel sheet that looks for a certain string of numbers in a list and deletes it in the top field, just like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> but automatic.

So if my toplist contains :

> 1 2 3 4 5 6
>   7 8 9 10 11 12

And the bottom list which is enter in by user, for example he types in:

> 4 3 11 12

It will remove those numbers (empty cell) from the toplist

[Sample spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0lxgffwu2pk0p06/List.xlsx)

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: i cant figure out how i make excel look in the toplist numbers for the   numbers in the bottomlist, now we doing it manually with CTRL + H but i was wondering if it was possible to do it with a formule

Comment: please make it more clear .. not getting even after having a look at you excel file

Comment: OK you got the top large field with those numbers those value's are static

Comment: When someone puts data in the bottom table (weekly) it checks the large table for matching value's and delete those that match

Comment: there are no formules to do this? because i got no experience with VBA yet

Comment: `there are no formules to do this?` - no, formulas can't change static cells

Comment: Just dont get confused with static cells i meant they dont change, the numbers stay the same

Comment: I uderstood, again, you can't do it with formulas.

Comment: OK simoco can i do it on another way? by marker the cells and instead of counting the empty cells i count the marked cells ?

Comment: ty for helping me btw Simoco

Comment: still unclear to me. What are you going to achive with counting marked cells?

Comment: So each line is a group of preset value's
Weekly we check the who has the correct value's, if a person reach like having all matching value they get price money

Now i use the replace function in excel to check em and use the formule empty cells to count how many value's are removed

Comment: try use this folmula in `O3` and drag it down: `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(COUNTIF($C$21:$H$26;E3:N3)>0))`. Is it what you need?

Comment: ty for helping i'll try to figure out to use VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can :

```
split Top List (with separator = space) into an array of string TList
split User List (with separator = space) into an array of string UList
For each value of UList
 if you can find an entry in TList
  remove TList
 end if
end for each
```

Comment: How do i apply this to my excel file ?